# Tengo un problema con este formulario, al momento de usar ajax el if que valida si esta vacio o no, lo toma como vacio aunque el input tenga texto

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Me dijeron que con ajax se podia hacer esto de validar con javascript para luego mandar por php datos a una base de datos, pero estoy medio perdido y no se si esta es la forma que se deberia hacer, en el siguiente codigo me pasa que el if para validar uno de los input vacios, siempre me tira como que esta vacio, haya texto ingresado o no, y esto hace que no se puedan mandar los datos a la base datos

```
<form action="Registro.php" method="POST" id="formAjax">
  <div class="titulo"><h2>Registrarse</h2></div>
  <div class="form-container">
<input type="text" name="nombre" class= "input" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
echo $_POST['nombre'];
} ?>">
<button type="submit" name="boton" id="Enviar" >Registrsarse</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

Codigo JavaScript

```
const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');

const nombreValor = nombre.value;


function checkInputs (input){
  input.classList+=' success';

}

$('#Enviar').on("click",function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
if (nombreValor.length == 0 || nombreValor =='') {
checkInputs(nombre);
 }else {
    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/Reg.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formAjax').serialize(),
    })

    .done(function (res){
        $('#respuesta').html(res)
    })
    .fail(function (){
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function (){
        console.log("complete");
    })
 
}
 
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Te lo toma como vacío porque es el valor que estás obteniendo al cargar el script y como está por fuera del evento click, nunca te va a obtener el nuevo, entonces, debes obtener el valor dentro de la función callback del evento click, ejemplo:

```js
const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');

function checkInputs (input){
  input.classList+=' success';

}

$( '#Enviar' ).on( "click", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Desde aquí debes obtener el valor, para que cada vez
    // que des click, cargue lo nuevo que tengas escrito en el input
    const nombreValor = nombre.value;

    if ( nombreValor.length == 0 || nombreValor =='' ) {
        checkInputs(nombre);
    }

}
```

Si el valor no te cambia después del primer click, cambia de `const` a `let`

Una recomendación que puedes hacer con **php** y dependiendo de la versión que estés usando, es utilizar el **Null Coalescing Operator** `null ?? 'otro valor'`, para que evites agregar una condicional `if` dentro del atributo value o cualquier otra parte.

Puedes reemplazar esto:

```php
<input value="<?php if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
echo $_POST['nombre'];
} ?>">
```

Por esto:

```php
<input value="<?= $_POST['nombre'] ?? '' ?>">
```